# Schedule PgAgent Job to run in every one minute every day

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I have installed PgAgent a job scheduling agent for PostgreSQL 9.6 + PgAdmin 4(V 1.5) on windows 7. I had successfully created job and run it. However, the problem is that I could not understand its scheduling functionality. I want to run a job in every one minute every day. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some study and test on this, I found that if I only provide start and end date , the job automatically executes in every one minute. This is what I was looking for. When end date reaches it will stop doing its work. You can do all this from the given interface or generate script (Right click on job and select create script) and modify that. When install PgAgent it creates catalog in PostGres database where you will find number of tables.These tables give us detail about job success/failure and job description.